# Ajax/PHP: Updating a Database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using Ajax with PHP to insert values taken from input into a table in phpmyadmin. I am working with camp, but I have a problem getting the value of input.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>inscription client</title>
    <script >
      function test() {
        r=document.getElementById('1');
        if (r.value.length !==9)
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="verifer le mot de passe";
        else  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="";
      }
      //////////////////////////////////////////
      function ajouter()
      {
        var cin=document.getElementById("cin").value;
        var nom=document.getElementById("nom").value;
        var mot_de_passe=document.getElementById("mot_de_passe").value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var url = "http://localhost/amir/inscrireClient.php?cin="+cin+"&nom="+nom+"&mot_de_passe="+mot_de_passe;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
          {

            if(this.responseText =="ok")
            {
              document.getElementById("2").innerHTML ="it woeks !";
              document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor="green";
            }
            else{
              document.getElementById("2").innerHTML="no";
              document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor="red";

            }
          };

          xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input   id ="cin" type="number" name="cin" value="123654789"  onblur="test()" required  >  
    <p style="color: red"   id="demo"></p> 
    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" value="aaa" placeholder="donner votre nom" >  <br> <br>
    <input type="password" id="mot_de_passe" name="mot_de_passe" value="aaa" placeholder="donner votre mot de passe" required=>  <br> <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="ajouter()">s'inscrire </button> 
    <p id="2" ></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this the PHP file:

```
<?php
include 'param.php'; 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 


$cin=$_GET['cin'];
$nom=$_GET['nom'];
$mot_de_passe=$_GET['mot_de_passe'];

try
{

  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8', $user, $passwd);
  $bdd->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
  die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$reponse = $bdd->exec( "insert into client(cin,nom,mot_de_passe) values ($cin,'$nom','$mot_de_passe')" );
if ($reponse->rowCount()>0) 
  echo "ok";
else        echo "non";
?>
```

It does not change in the database:
[image]

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC4KM.png)

Comment: you have no input-element with that 'id': `var cin=document.getElementById("cin").value;`. You've set the 'name' not the 'id'

Comment: And you have a syntax error in query text.

Comment: i changed the id but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Fix your sql statement:

```
$reponse = $bdd->exec( "insert into client(cin,nom,mot_de_passe) values ($cin,'$nom','$mot_de_passe)'" );
```

'$mot_de_passe)' part. You should put single quote before closing the parenthesis. And assuming $cin is numeric.

Comment: i changed the sql statement but it doesn't work
look at  the picture at the link

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/amir/inscrireClient.php?cin=123654789&nom=aaa&mot_de_passe=aaa. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: have you tried allowing methods - especially GET in your case: header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'); And put the header functions at the top of your php script - before everything.

Answer (score 0):

/* You should put your  after html body, getElementById method return null because html DOM has not loaded. Check frontend before checking PHP code. */

```
 // $reponse = $bdd->exec( "insert into client(cin,nom,mot_de_passe) values ($cin,'$nom','$mot_de_passe')" );
    
    $sql = "insert into client(cin, nom, mot_de_passe) values (?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $cin);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $nom);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $mot_de_passe);
    
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: A code-only answer is probably not optimal. Would you care to explain what the code does / how it helps to solve the problem? Thanks.